# How to run memory viewer on VScode on mac

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I would like to look into how's c lang works with checking by memory viewer on VS Code on Mac.
An extension of C/C++ from microsoft was able to install to my mac and works fine, but the extension of MemoryView from microsoft does not work. (Actually the MemoryView can be installed and can see MEMORY tab but status is "No debugger attached".)

Does anybody know the way to check memory behavior with VS code on Mac??

I did ask google but I could not find any helpful info.

My expectation is that can track memory behavior on MEMORY tab.

Comment: By "C lang" do you mean _[Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)_ specifically, or the _C language_ in general?

Comment: "C language in general"

Comment: You might want to talk to the developers directly, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions

Comment: it's not clear to me whether debugging is working for you at all. Please provide an exact procedure to reproduce what you are looking at. see also [ask] and [mre].